# Remove urls using PHP

Tags: php, regex

I'd like to only remove the anchor tags and the actual urls.
For instance, `<a href="http://www.example.com">test www.example.com</a>` would become `test`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complement gd1's answer, this will get all the URLs:

```
// http(s)://
$txt = preg_replace('|https?://www\.[a-z\.0-9]+|i', '', $txt);
// only www.
$txt = preg_replace('|www\.[a-z\.0-9]+|i', '', $txt);
```

Comment: No prob. Note that I adapted this from a webpage I wrote a while ago which had slightly different requirements. It should work, but it may need a bit of tweaking for your specific case.

Comment: Please see the example I mentioned earlier.

Comment: @Lior: Ok, that was overly complicated in effect. This seems to work, although there may be some cases I haven't considered.

Comment: You should remove "www" from the regular expression since not all URLs start with it.
Also add characters that are url-valid, such as '/-_?&' etc.

Comment: ``$txt = preg_replace('#(https?|ftp)://[^ ]+ #i', '', $txt);`` any non-space following http:// (or ftp://) up-to and including the following space.

Answer (score 4):

I often use:

`$string = preg_replace("/<a[^>]+>/i", "", $string);`

And remember that `strip_tags` can remove all the tags from a string, except the ones specified in a "white list". That's **not** what you want, but I tell you also this for exhaustiveness.

EDIT: I found the original source where I got that regex. I want to cite the author, for fairness: http://bavotasan.com/tutorials/using-php-to-remove-an-html-tag-from-a-string/

Comment: I actually also need to remove urls, as you can see in the example I mentioned.

Comment: the regex I provided removes "the anchor tags and the actual urls". Do you want to remove also the "www.example.com" which is OUT of the anchor? That would be a bit more complicated, because not all urls start with www. Do you really neeed it?

Comment: Just the ones that contain http or www.

Answer (score 2):

you should consider using the PHP's [DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) library for this job.

Regex is not the right tool for HTML parsing.

Here is an example:

```
// Create a new DOM Document to hold our webpage structure 
$xml = new DOMDocument(); 

// Load the html's contents into DOM 
$xml->loadHTML($html); 

$links = $xml->getElementsByTagName('a');

//Loop through each <a> tags and replace them by their text content    
for ($i = $links->length - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    $linkNode = $links->item($i);
    $lnkText = $linkNode->textContent;
    $newTxtNode = $xml->createTextNode($lnkText);
    $linkNode->parentNode->replaceChild($newTxtNode, $linkNode);
}
```

#### Note:

- It's important to use a regressive loop here, because when calling [replaceChild](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.replacechild.php), if the old node has a different name from the new node, it will be removed from the list once it has been replaced, and some of the links would not be replaced.
- This code doesn't remove urls from the text inside a node, you can use the preg_replace from nico on $lnkText before the createTextNode line. It's always better to isolate parts from html using DOM, and then use regular expressions on these text only parts.