# Remove all urls from text with php

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove urls using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844442/remove-urls-using-php)

I'm trying to figure out the best way to remove URLs from text with php. I've looked at a bunch of different sites and questions on here but can't quite piece it all together.

I would like to remove all URLs like the following:

1. www.website.com
2. http://www.website.com
3. website.com
4. website.com/test
5. <tag>www.website.com</tag> (where <tag> is any html tag)
6. (www.website.com)

I've tried a few solutions i found on here, but i couldn't figure out how to get web addresses with bordering characters not part of the web address, i.e. parenthesis or within an HTML tag like <strong>

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is a little bit confusing. Could you re-phrase the question to make it more clear?

Comment: How much do you care about it removing things that aren't actually URLs, but *look* like URLs (such as the language 'ASP.net' or the office suite formerly known as 'OpenOffice.org')?

Comment: @DarylGill Sorry i didn't notice the messy formatting (first time posting a question here... i think). I cleaned it up and added a part

Comment: @Kitsune I don't care if false positives get removed, as long as *most* web addresses get removed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps...

```
// http(s)://
    $txt = preg_replace('|https?://www\.[a-z\.0-9]+|i', '', $txt);
    // only www.
    $txt = preg_replace('|www\.[a-z\.0-9]+|i', '', $txt);
```

Or:

```
$Var = str_replace("itemtoreplace", "replacewith", $variabletoremovefrom");
```

[PHP Str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Use:
[Remove urls using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844442/remove-urls-using-php?rq=1)

For reference.

Comment: Thanks i'll try this out later and let you know

Comment: Also, OP asked for the form 
"<tag>www.website.com</tag> (where <tag> is any html tag)", too: this way, <div>something.com</div> would be replaced with <div></div>.

Comment: I added this after those and it got http:// google.com. $txt = preg_replace('|https?://[a-z\.0-9]+|i', 'WEBSITE', $txt);

Comment: I also added /?\S* to get everything after the slash